# NativeScript iOS VersaPlayer implementation

Tags: ios, nativescript

I am trying to implement [VersaPlayer](https://github.com/josejuanqm/VersaPlayer) for iOS like this:

public player() {

```
let versa = TestViewController.new();
let appWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow;
appWindow.rootViewController.presentViewControllerAnimatedCompletion(versa, true, null);
```

}

`TestViewController:`

> export class TestViewController extends UIViewController {
>
> ```
> public viewDidLoad() {
>
>     super.viewDidLoad();
>
>     let url = NSURL.URLWithString("https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_10mb.mp4")
>     let item = VersaPlayerItem.playerItemWithURL(url);
>
>     let player = VersaPlayerView.alloc();
>     player.setWithItem(item);
>
>     this.view.addSubview(player);
>
> } }
> ```

But I am getting this error:

```
NativeScript caught signal 11.
Native Stack:
1   0x10301d84f sig_handler(int)
2   0x107614b5d _sigtramp
3   0x0
4   0x10755ab4d libunwind::UnwindCursor<libunwind::LocalAddressSpace, libunwind::Registers_x86_64>::step()
5   0x10755ee4c _Unwind_RaiseException
6   0x1071374aa __cxa_throw
7   0x105b4ebfa _objc_exception_destructor(void*)
8   0x106cfa735 +[NSException raise:format:]
9   0x105ac8b89 $s11VersaPlayer0aB4ViewC6layout4view4intoySo6UIViewC_AHSgtF
10  0x105ac89c0 $s11VersaPlayer0aB4ViewC7prepareyyF
11  0x105ac96fa $s11VersaPlayer0aB4ViewC3set4itemyAA0aB4ItemCSg_tF
12  0x105ac9a7c $s11VersaPlayer0aB4ViewC3set4itemyAA0aB4ItemCSg_tFTo
13  0x1039b263d ffi_call_unix64
14  0x122a3b860
JS Stack:
1   setWithItem@[native code]
2   viewDidLoad@file:///src/app/item/items.component.ts:125:27
3   presentViewControllerAnimatedCompletion@[native code]
4   player@file:///src/app/item/items.component.ts:111:77
5   @:17:33
6   callWithDebugContext@file:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:30308:0
7   dispatchEvent@file:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:19858:0
8   @file:///node_modules/nativescript-angular/renderer.js:241:0
9   onInvoke@file:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:26255:0
10  run@file:///node_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:138:0
11  zonedCallback@file:///node_modules/nativescript-angular/renderer.js:240:0
12  notify@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js:110:0
13  _emit@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js:127:0
14  tap@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/button/button.js:216:0
15  UIApplicationMain@[native code]
16  _start@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:277:0
```

Also I tried using `Placeholder` like this:

```
<Placeholder (creatingView)="creatingView($event)" height="200"></Placeholder>

public creatingView(args: CreateViewEventData) {


    let url = NSURL.URLWithString("https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_10mb.mp4")

    let player =   VersaPlayer.playerWithURL(url)

    args.view = player; 
}
```

Error:

```
NativeScript caught signal 11.
Native Stack:
1   0x1027cf84f sig_handler(int)
2   0x1064e0b5d _sigtramp
3   0x0
4   0x106426b4d libunwind::UnwindCursor<libunwind::LocalAddressSpace, libunwind::Registers_x86_64>::step()
5   0x10642ae4c _Unwind_RaiseException
6   0x1060034aa __cxa_throw
7   0x104a1abfa _objc_exception_destructor(void*)
8   0x105be4c94 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
9   0x105bcb623 ___forwarding___
10  0x105bcd418 _CF_forwarding_prep_0
11  0x1083923d3 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
12  0x10316463d ffi_call_unix64
13  0x12214caa0
JS Stack:
1   addSubview@[native code]
2   _addViewToNativeVisualTree@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.js:565:0
3   _setupUI@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:529:0
4   @file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:533:0
5   eachChildView@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:125:0
6   eachChild@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view-common.js:992:0
7   _setupUI@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:532:0
8   @file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:533:0
9   eachChildView@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:125:0
10  eachChild@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view-common.js:992:0
11  _setupUI@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:532:0
12  @file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:533:0
13  eachChildView@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/content-view/content-view.js:70:0
14  eachChildView@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/page/page-common.js:126:0
15  eachChild@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view-common.js:992:0
16  _setupUI@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:532:0
17  _addViewCore@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:431:0
18  _addView@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:420:0
19  viewWillAppear@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/page/page.js:81:0
20  UIApplicationMain@[native code]
21  _start@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:277:0
22  run@file:///node_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js:305:0
23  bootstrapNativeScriptApp@fil<…>
```

In where I am doing mistake? Please give me idea.

Comment: You don't have to create a UIViewController, you could host the Player in a new Page if you want the player alone on screen. Can you post the complete code in creatingView, you are suppose to `args.view`  to native player view which seems missing.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I used `args.view` but it missed when I pasted here. I have edited the post. Please have a look.

Comment: As the [POD is written in Swift](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries#apis-written-in-swift) you will have to make sure whether the methods are accessible via Objective C

Comment: Yes, I followed that to do customization

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented versa player in one of my apps here is how I did it.
Add UIView on the storyboard and set the class to VersaPlayerView.
 Get the reference of that view in your view controller as videoView, or any other name you would like.

variables:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: VersaPlayerView!
     var playerItem: VersaPlayerItem?
```

Load video function which i'm calling from ViewDidLoad()

```
 fileprivate func loadVideo(url: String) {
    if let url = URL.init(string: url) {
        playerItem = VersaPlayerItem(url: url)
        videoView.set(item: playerItem)
        videoView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }
}
```